# HighCharts JS showing extra xAxis parameter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with HighCharts JS, and am encountering some odd behavior.  I am creating a basic heatmap, with days of week, and hours per day.  It works great except for an odd "extra" parameter oddly labeled 24 (see screenshot)

[image: Chart]

Also note the "extra space" at the bottom.  My `yAxis` parameters:

```
yAxis: {
categories: ['12am', 
             '1am', 
             '2am', 
             '3am', 
             '4am', 
             '5am', 
             '6am', 
             '7am', 
             '8am', 
             '9am', 
             '10am', 
             '11am', 
             '12pm', 
             '1pm', 
             '2pm', 
             '3pm', 
             '4pm', 
             '5pm', 
             '6pm', 
             '7pm', 
             '8pm', 
             '9pm', 
             '10pm', 
             '11pm'],
```

Note that there are **24** parameters, but none are *labeled* **24**.  I am thoroughly confused.  See my full snippet below, (also note that I have exactly 24 plot points for the `Y Axis` in my snippet.  What am I doing wrong?

```js
Highcharts.chart('users_by_day', {

                        chart: {
                            type: 'heatmap',
                            marginTop: 15,
                            marginBottom: 40,
                            plotBorderWidth: 1
                        },
                        exporting: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        title: false,

                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            categories: ['12am',
                                '1am',
                                '2am',
                                '3am',
                                '4am',
                                '5am',
                                '6am',
                                '7am',
                                '8am',
                                '9am',
                                '10am',
                                '11am',
                                '12pm',
                                '1pm',
                                '2pm',
                                '3pm',
                                '4pm',
                                '5pm',
                                '6pm',
                                '7pm',
                                '8pm',
                                '9pm',
                                '10pm',
                                '11pm'],
                            title: null,
                            reversed: true
                        },

                        accessibility: {
                            point: {
                                descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                                    var ix = point.index + 1,
                                        xName = getPointCategoryName(point, 'x'),
                                        yName = getPointCategoryName(point, 'y'),
                                        val = point.value;
                                    return ix + '. ' + xName + ' sales ' + yName + ', ' + val + '.';
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        colorAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                        },

                        legend: {
                            align: 'right',
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            margin: 0,
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 24,
                            symbolHeight: 280
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'y') + ', ' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '<br />' +
                                    this.point.value + '</b> Visitors <b>';
                            }
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name: 'Sales per employee',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            //data: graph_data,

                            data: [

                                [0, 0, 0],
                                [1, 0, 1],
                                [2, 0, 1],
                                [3, 0, 1],
                                [4, 0, 0],
                                [5, 0, 0],
                                [6, 0, 1],

                                [0, 1, 1],
                                [1, 1, 0],
                                [2, 1, 0],
                                [3, 1, 0],
                                [4, 1, 0],
                                [5, 1, 0],
                                [6, 1, 0],

                                [0, 2, 0],
                                [1, 2, 0],
                                [2, 2, 0],
                                [3, 2, 1],
                                [4, 2, 0],
                                [5, 2, 0],
                                [6, 2, 0],

                                [0, 3, 0],
                                [1, 3, 0],
                                [2, 3, 0],
                                [3, 3, 0],
                                [4, 3, 0],
                                [5, 3, 0],
                                [6, 3, 0],

                                [0, 4, 0],
                                [1, 4, 0],
                                [2, 4, 0],
                                [3, 4, 0],
                                [4, 4, 0],
                                [5, 4, 0],
                                [6, 4, 0],

                                [0, 5, 0],
                                [1, 5, 0],
                                [2, 5, 1],
                                [3, 5, 0],
                                [4, 5, 0],
                                [5, 5, 1],
                                [6, 5, 0],

                                [0, 6, 0],
                                [1, 6, 0],
                                [2, 6, 3],
                                [3, 6, 0],
                                [4, 6, 2],
                                [5, 6, 1],
                                [6, 6, 0],

                                [0, 7, 0],
                                [1, 7, 0],
                                [2, 7, 1],
                                [3, 7, 0],
                                [4, 7, 3],
                                [5, 7, 2],
                                [6, 7, 0],

                                [0, 8, 3],
                                [1, 8, 2],
                                [2, 8, 3],
                                [3, 8, 0],
                                [4, 8, 4],
                                [5, 8, 3],
                                [6, 8, 1],

                                [0, 9, 4],
                                [1, 9, 4],
                                [2, 9, 4],
                                [3, 9, 4],
                                [4, 9, 5],
                                [5, 9, 0],
                                [6, 9, 1],

                                [0, 10, 1],
                                [1, 10, 1],
                                [2, 10, 1],
                                [3, 10, 4],
                                [4, 10, 7],
                                [5, 10, 1],
                                [6, 10, 1],

                                [0, 11, 2],
                                [1, 11, 0],
                                [2, 11, 5],
                                [3, 11, 2],
                                [4, 11, 5],
                                [5, 11, 5],
                                [6, 11, 0],

                                [0, 12, 0],
                                [1, 12, 3],
                                [2, 12, 7],
                                [3, 12, 22],
                                [4, 12, 5],
                                [5, 12, 2],
                                [6, 12, 0],

                                [0, 13, 0],
                                [1, 13, 3],
                                [2, 13, 3],
                                [3, 13, 2],
                                [4, 13, 3],
                                [5, 13, 2],
                                [6, 13, 0],

                                [0, 14, 1],
                                [1, 14, 1],
                                [2, 14, 0],
                                [3, 14, 0],
                                [4, 14, 20],
                                [5, 14, 2],
                                [6, 14, 0],

                                [0, 15, 1],
                                [1, 15, 4],
                                [2, 15, 1],
                                [3, 15, 0],
                                [4, 15, 2],
                                [5, 15, 2],
                                [6, 15, 0],

                                [0, 16, 3],
                                [1, 16, 1],
                                [2, 16, 1],
                                [3, 16, 0],
                                [4, 16, 1],
                                [5, 16, 0],
                                [6, 16, 0],

                                [0, 17, 1],
                                [1, 17, 0],
                                [2, 17, 1],
                                [3, 17, 0],
                                [4, 17, 0],
                                [5, 17, 1],
                                [6, 17, 0],

                                [0, 18, 1],
                                [1, 18, 2],
                                [2, 18, 1],
                                [3, 18, 1],
                                [4, 18, 2],
                                [5, 18, 2],
                                [6, 18, 0],

                                [0, 19, 0],
                                [1, 19, 0],
                                [2, 19, 2],
                                [3, 19, 3],
                                [4, 19, 1],
                                [5, 19, 0],
                                [6, 19, 1],

                                [0, 20, 1],
                                [1, 20, 1],
                                [2, 20, 1],
                                [3, 20, 3],
                                [4, 20, 1],
                                [5, 20, 1],
                                [6, 20, 0],

                                [0, 21, 1],
                                [1, 21, 1],
                                [2, 21, 1],
                                [3, 21, 2],
                                [4, 21, 0],
                                [5, 21, 4],
                                [6, 21, 0],

                                [0, 22, 0],
                                [1, 22, 0],
                                [2, 22, 1],
                                [3, 22, 0],
                                [4, 22, 0],
                                [5, 22, 0],
                                [6, 22, 0],

                                [0, 23, 0],
                                [1, 23, 0],
                                [2, 23, 0],
                                [3, 23, 1],
                                [4, 23, 1],
                                [5, 23, 1],
                                [6, 23, 0]
                            ],

                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false,
                            }
                        }],

                        responsive: {
                            rules: [{
                                condition: {
                                    maxWidth: 500
                                },
                                chartOptions: {
                                    xAxis: {
                                        labels: {
                                            formatter: function () {
                                                return this.value.charAt(0) +  this.value.charAt(1)+  this.value.charAt(2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }

                    });
                    
                    
                    
                    
function getPointCategoryName(point, dimension) {
    var series = point.series,
    isY = dimension === 'y',
    axis = series[isY ? 'yAxis' : 'xAxis'];
    return axis.categories[point[isY ? 'y' : 'x']];
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="users_by_day"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who runs into this issue ..  It will label the number of fields you have at the bottom if the graph is too tall for the parent div.  I made it (the parent div) 50px taller and solved the issue.